# Adding multiple tables on one excel sheet onto Tableau

Tags: excel, tableau-api

The excel files I'm working with have multiple tables on one sheet separated by empty rows or in some cases empty columns. I'm having trouble separating these tables and adding them to Tableau. I have multiple sheets with multiple tables. I also have multiple excel workbooks for each year.

[image]

Sometimes I have 7-8 tables each below the other.I want to add each distinct table into tableau and compare the data in one table in one excel workbook by another table in another excel workbook by year.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Tableau are you using? and why don't you turn on excel.
You can install [Tableau Data Tool](http://kbcdn.tableausoftware.com/data/tableau_data_tool.zip) and get started on data cleansing.
Alternatively you can also use the Data parsing tool available in TD 9.0 on-wards. It will automatically ask you if you want to tune in the data after connecting to the excel file.